# Add Service Console to a community?

Tags: user, console, community, service

We want to create a community for field staff and provide them access to the service console.

Since service console is a custom application, I am not able to add it to the Community.

By default, when a community is created, its profile is a "guest user". Hence I am not able to add the custom app's to this profile?

Has anyone come across this type of issue? Is it possible to add the custom app ( service console) to a community?

Comment: What license are you using? Cases can be accessed using a customer community license. You could also do it with a HVCP license. You won't get the same service console as you have from within Salesforce. See [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) for more on the different licenses and links to other User Licenses.